# UI object, on samelevel of XAML Tree, as CommandParameter

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, relativesource

I have an XAML tree as follows:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
               <DataGrid>
                      <DataGrid.Resources>
                              <CheckBox Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="??" />
                      </DataGrid.Resources>
               </DataGrid>
              <StackPanel>
                    <ChartLegend>
                    </ChartLegend>
                    <DataChart>
                    </DataChart>
              </stackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to have `DataChart` object as `CommandParameter` on `ViewModel` from a `Command` on `DataGrid`.

My Findings:

I'm getting `DockPanel` object as `CommandParameter`, then I have to apply method `FindName("")` to get the `DataChart`. And do further modifications.

But I want the `DataChart` object directly, to avoid `TypeCasting` or searching down the Tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep datachart as a named resource in your `DockPanel` resources and use static resource binding to command parameter. Then use `ContentControl` to host it.

like this...

```
    <DockPanel>
            <DockPanel.Resources>
                 <DataChart x:Key="MyDataChart">
                 </DataChart>
            </DockPanel.Resources>
            <DataGrid>
                   <DataGrid.Resources>
                           <CheckBox 
                                 Command="{Binding Command}"
                                 CommandParameter="{StaticResource MyDataChart}" />
                   </DataGrid.Resources>
            </DataGrid>
           <StackPanel>
                 <ChartLegend>
                 </ChartLegend>
                 <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyDataChart}"/>
           </stackPanel>
     </DockPanel>
```

Hoping that you wont use **same** `MyDataChart` to host to another area (as that would result in "visual tree parent disconnect" error).

Although I must ask you this... why is there a lonely `CheckBox` in your `DataGrid` resources?

**Also your's and mine solution breaks MVVM because we are supplying a UI control (Chart control) to a View Model.**

Comment: This is a major drawback in XamDataChart that ItemSource cannot be updated through Binding, as it's a ReadOnly Property. It can only be updated through Code with UI Control.

Comment: oh and one more thing  [:(] ... I am not sure if CheckBox's Command / CommandParameter property works. Its deprecated somehow. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/006629cb-e2fe-48ee-ba12-803f1748151e/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know this and I'm following this pattern only. This code was just a mere representation.

Comment: Now I have one more Query, I want to make this Checkbox, a general checkbox in Window.Resources and use it for more than 1 DataGrid. Can you give suggestions? Is it possible through RelativeSource? I guess yes.

Comment: Nope ... a UI control cannot be set under more than one parents... for that we use Templates. So in your case wrap your CheckBox under a `DataTemplate` and then set that `DataTemplate` to a suitable parent (such as a `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` or `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` etc.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3584/discussion-between-varun-jain-and-angelwpf)